# Does deleting Cosmos DB container consume RUs?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

There are lot of junk documents in a Cosmos DB container. Is it better to bulk delete documents or drop the container and re-create it? Bulk delete consumes RUs, but what about deleting container? Does it consumes the RU to delete documents before dropping the container?

Comment: You mean the container is entirely junk documents or you need to preserve some portion of them?

Comment: @MartinSmith there are few docs which are important, but they will be reproduced if they don't exist in container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no "right" answer - only you can decide which approach is "better" but... from an objective perspective:

- Deletion of a container has negligible cost, and it's a one-time cost (that is... it's one single "delete" cost). And to your question regarding cost of deleting all the documents when taking the "delete collection" route: nope - it's just a collection-drop - you aren't charged RU for every document being removed, when dropping a collection.
- Deleting documents, in bulk, would consume RU for *every document deleted* - it would absolutely cost RU, and runs the risk of throttling, depending on how aggressive your deletion activity is
- Deleting all documents requires you to consider that deletes could occur across partitions - plan accordingly
- If you delete the collection, there could be a time period where your app is now throwing exceptions due to the collection not existing (until you re-create the collection, which could take several seconds)
- When re-creating a collection, be sure to re-create any related attributes of the collection as well (custom indexing, stored procedures, etc)

As an alternative to bulk-deleting, you can also take advantage of ttl to let old documents *expire*.

Comment: One comment about the deletion of the Container. Because you provision RU at the Container level commonly, if you delete the Container, it is not using the RU of the Container (because it's being deleted). Deleting Containers, just like Creating Containers is a management operation. Management operations do not consume RU from your provisioned RU. They consume this pool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#metadata-request-limits

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta - yup I should have clarified that (I *did* omit RU in that "one time cost" description but... I left out explicit callout of management plane). Annnnnd... also worth noting that there can be management operation throttling too...

Comment: For that scenario, this guide is useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/troubleshoot-request-rate-too-large?tabs=resource-specific#rate-limiting-on-metadata-requests